# how to pass $(this) of select2 inside ajax parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I need to pass $(this) of select2 inside ajax to get data-url like like code below it, $(this).data("url") not working.

```
$(".select-ajax").select2({
    allowClear: $(this).data('allowclear') ? $(this).data('allowclear') : false,
    ajax: {
        url: $(this).data("url"),
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
        return markup;
    }, // let our custom formatter work
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});
```

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: No, and sends request to URL of page not data-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this and similar situations is to set a constant to refer to.

```
const selectAjax = $(".select-ajax");
selectAjax.select2({
    allowClear: selectAjax.data('allowclear') ? selectAjax.data('allowclear') : false,
    ajax: {
        url: selectAjax.data("url"),
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
        return markup;
    }, // let our custom formatter work
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `this` as a variable.

```
var that = $(this);
that.select2({
   ...
   //other code
   url: $(that).attr("data-url")
   //other code
});
```